# How to fill in the base of this geometry for printing

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode

I would like to fill in the base of this geometry (red lines) so that it can be printed as a Vase. I thought the boolean operators would work but to no avail. Any tips?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You mean you want that stat shape to be filled in or you want that entire part to be flat and cylindrical?

Comment: I want to retain the material within the Star boundary and remove the outside, ie remove the circular boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't need that cylinder for the base, delete it. I suppose you wanted the height of the cylinder as the thickness of the vase bottom. The best thing to do with such a geometry will be the following:

1. Select the star object and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go into *Edit Mode*.
2. Select everything with <kbd>A</kbd>, then convert *Tris to Quads* with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. This is not necessary for 3D printing but makes the next steps easier.

[image: tris to quads]

3. Deselect everything with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then select the second row of vertices from the bottom on the **inside** of the object. You can do this by clicking between two vertices in a row and holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>. You have to repeat this on all sides, hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> while left-clicking to add selections.

[image: select edge loop]

4. Now that you've selected the inner edge loop, press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill the hole with a new face.

[image: fill inner face]

5. Next select the row of vertices below the new face. After selecting the complete edge loop, hit <kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete* > *Vertices* to delete the edge in order to delete the two bottom rows of faces.

[image: delete bottom faces]

6. Now select the last bottom row of vertices on the inside. After the complete edge loop is selected, press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill the bottom with a new face.

[image: select last row]

[image: fill bottom]

7. At last, check *Face Orientation* in the *Overlays* menu to see if the object shows completely blue faces. Also look inside the vase from the top. If there is anything showing up in red, select all with <kbd>A</kbd>, then press <kbd>sHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to *Recalculate Normals*.

[image: face orientation]

Comment: perfect instructions! Thanks! The last step was crucial to remove the "Bad Contig Edges" in the 3d-print tool.

Comment: @user9106985 Good to know, I had no idea what you needed for 3D printing, I just created a bottom for the vase 